NetworkManager Keeps Disconnecting
I connect to the internet via WiFi and it happens that occasionally and recurrently the connection keeps dropping and coming back on its own.
It's true that there are several similar topics to this one, however, I haven't found any that are actually the same as my case. I managed to collect some logs, but I don't have the necessary knowledge to understand what they mean. So, any help to solve this would be REALLY appreciated!
Machine 1 specs (from neofetch):
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
Host: Inspiron 15 3520
Kernel: 6.1.0-20-amd64
WM: i3


Host 1 dmesg logs

Host 1 NetworkManager (v1.42.4-1) logs

Host 1 wpa_supplicant (v2:2.10-12) logs


Output of inxi -N:
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: rtw_8821ce

If you have any other relevant information that I can provide, please let me know.
EDIT 1:
A few days passed and something happened that was very strange to me. I have another notebook (which I will call machine 2) and now it is presenting the same problem, however, it has different logs. Meanwhile, machine 1 (the first notebook I had mentioned) is working normally now, without connection drops.
Machine 2 specs (from neofetch):
OS: Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid x86_64
Host: Aspire A515-51 V2.02
Kernel: 6.7.12-amd64
WM: i3


Host 2 dmesg logs

Host 2 NetworkManager (v1.46.0-1) logs

Host 2 wpa_supplicant (v2:2.10-21) logs


Output of inxi -N:
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    driver: r8169
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: ath10k_pci

EDIT 2:
I added the information for the tal command because I thought it might be useful too.
EDIT 3:
Unintentionally, I ended up getting another observation about the problem... I had to go somewhere outside my home network (to a friend's house) and I took my second notebook (machine 2) which was the only computer connected to the network and consequently the only Linux with NetworkManager running and to my surprise, the disconnection problem stopped happening... when I returned to my house and connected to the network, the problem returned, exactly the same. Can I assume then that the problem is that there is another device (machine 1) on the network that also has NetworkManger running? Why and how is this possible?! How to deal with this situation?

There's a reason I lovingly call it NetworkMangler ... ;) turning it off/removing it is the first thing I do in any linux installation I lay my hands on.

@tink How do you manage the network?

systemd & config files ...
